# Typo in the help section

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, grammar

On the help page [How do I search?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching) it says

```
use title: followed by the your search term.
```

where either **your** or **the** should be removed.

Comment: @ProgramFOX Wow now I am making a typo in the typo-request oO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep. I've corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out.